# Hibernate: Ordering objects based on age

Tags: java, hibernate, datetime

I have 2 Hibernate entities: `Kennel` and `Dog`.

I would like to write a method that determines what the *"oldest" Kennel* in my database is.

This would be trivial if the Kennel Entity had a "created" or similar column, but it **does not**.

However, in my Dog entity there is a `born` field (DateTime) that maps to the `BORN column`.

Using this Dog field I would like to define the **oldest Kennel** by *which has the oldest dog in it*.

A Kennel can have many dogs but a dog can only have one kennel.

How can I do this?

**Entities:**

**Kennel:**

```
@Entity
@Table(name = "KENNEL")
public class Kennel
{
    @Id
    private String id;

    @Column(name = "LOCATION")
    private String location;

}
```

**Dog:**

```
@Entity
@Table(name = "DOG")
public class Dog
{
    @Id
    private String id;

    @Column(name = "NAME")
    private String name;

    @Column(name = "BORN")
    private DateTime created;

    @Column(name= "KENNEL_ID)
    private String kennelId;        

   @ManyToOne(cascade = CascadeType.ALL)
    @JoinColumn(name = "KENNEL_ID")
    private Kennel kennel;

}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Trying to implement @Mark's suggestion.

Create a named query in your `Dog` class as shown below and invoke it from your DAO.

```
@Entity
@Table(name = "DOG")
@NamedQueries({
   @NamedQuery(name="Dog.findOldestKennel", query="SELECT d.kennel 
       FROM Dog d order by d.created ASC LIMIT 1"),
   @NamedQuery(name="Dog.getAllKennelsInAgeOrder", query="SELECT d.kennel 
       FROM Dog d order by d.created ASC")
})
public class Dog {
    @Id
    private String id;

    @Column(name = "NAME")
    private String name;

    @Column(name = "BORN")
    private DateTime created;

    @Column(name= "KENNEL_ID)
    private String kennelId;        

    @ManyToOne(cascade = CascadeType.ALL)
    @JoinColumn(name = "KENNEL_ID")
    private Kennel kennel;

}
```

A Sample DAO method, using Hibernate entityManager is shown below (your project implementation may differ) for getting all kennels in the order that you said. Here we invoke the named query created in the `Dog` class and return the resultlist.

```
public List<Kennel> getAllKennels(){
   try{
        // name of the desired NamedQuery to run should be given 
        Query queryStr = this.entityManager
            .createNamedQuery("Dog.getAllKennelsInAgeOrder");             
        List<Kennel> kennels =  queryStr.getResultList();

        if(null != kennels && !kennels.isEmpty()){
            return kennels;
        } else {
            return Collections.emptyList();
        }
    } catch (Exception e) {
        LOGGER.error("Exception Occcured in getAllKennels ", e);
    }
}
```

Comment: Ok thanks, but then how do I order the rest of the Kennels also? I.e. from oldest to youngest?

Comment: Simply remove the `LIMIT 1` at the end of the query. That would return the whole list of the kennels, ordered oldest  to youngest.

Comment: Thanks, can you give an example of using this? Sorry I am very new to using SQL queries

Answer (score 1):

Why not just find the oldest dog, which like you said is trivial, and then get the Kennel using `dog.kennel`?

Comment: Im not sure what you mean? Can you post an example? Thanks

Comment: I just mean perform a query for the oldest dog instead of the oldest kennel. Once you get the oldest dog, as an object, in your Java code, just grab the reference to the kennel that the dog object belongs to.

Comment: Ok, but then how do I order the rest of the Kennels also? I.e. from oldest to youngest?

Comment: @java123999 That wasn't part of your original question.